# Understanding tz offset discrepancy on different systems

Tags: go, timezone

Hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong, or misunderstanding.
I was using the time pkg in the Go Sandbox, to become familiar with how to use the timezone specific functions correctly.
Even though I already knew some of the offsets, I used the following site to double check myself : https://documentation.mersive.com/content/topics/api-timezones.htm.
In this case, when I ask for the offset for "America/New_York", I expect -14400.
However, when I ran the following on the Go Sandbox, I get -18000 instead:
https://play.golang.org/p/aU0JFHzueU1

```
americatz, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
}

t := time.Now().In(americatz)
zone, offset := t.Zone()
fmt.Printf("%v :: %v\n", zone, offset)
```

I noticed that when I brought the same code over to a linux machine, it did exactly what I expected. I'm nervous, because I don't have a firm understanding why the two output's for a very common tz would be different.
I know enough that `LoadLocation` looks for a zipfile from the ZONEINFO env var. Otherwise it'll look in other system places like the `$GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip`.

Is it really just plain and simple that the Go Server the code runs on vs the linux server have different zone info files? And if I want the exact same behavior across all systems... does this mean I need to always load in and set my own ZONEINFO variable? I feel like most people would expect -14400...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the playground the [time is set](https://blog.golang.org/playground#TOC_3.) to "2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC" because "This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them deterministic output." (from the 'About' box).

This can have an impact on the timezone offset due to daylight savings. The following will give the answer you are expecting:

```
today := time.Date(2020,10,16,0,0,0,0,americatz)
zone, offset = today.Zone()
fmt.Printf("%v :: %v\n", zone, offset)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nojcVaU25Sa)

Further detail:

Due to daylight savings the offset changes depending upon the time; for example:

`time.Date(2020,10,16,0,0,0,0,americatz).Zone()` will return an offest of `-14400` whereas `time.Date(2020,1,16,0,0,0,0,americatz).Zone()` would return `-18000`.

It just so happens that the time that `now()` returns in the playground (`2009-11-10`) is `EST` (daylight savings ended Sunday, 1 November 2009, 2:00 a.m.) rather than `EDT`. If you run your test again in a month you will not see this difference because both times will be in `EST`.

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you . Just so I really understand this, Date takes into consideration daylight savings, which has an impact on offsets, where the the go playground does not?

Comment: It still works the same in the playground, the "current date and time" in playground is just a fixed value for performance reasons.